# Ruby: intercept popen system call and log stdout and stderr to same file

Tags: ruby, logging, stdout, stderr, popen3

In ruby code I am running a system call with Open3.popen3 and using the resultant IO for stdout and stderr to do some log message formatting before writing to one log file. I was wondering what would be the best way to do this so log messages will maintain the correct order, note I need to do separate formatting for error messages as for stdout messages.

Here's my current code (Assume logger is thread safe)

```rb
Open3.popen3("my_custom_script with_some_args") do |_in, stdout, stderr|
  stdout_thr = Thread.new do
    while line = stdout.gets.chomp
      logger.info(format(:info, line))
    end
  end
  stderr_thr = Thread.new do
    while line = stderr.gets.chomp
      logger.error(format(:error, line))
    end
  end
  [stdout_thr, stderr_thr].each(&:join)
end
```

This has worked for me so far, but I'm not so confident that I can guarantee the correct order of the log messages. Is there a better way?

Comment: How are you able to determine that the messages are in the correct order after they have been written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is not possible with a guarantee. First thing to note is that your code could only possibly order based on the time that the data was received, not when it was produced, which is not quite the same. The only way to guarantee this would be to do something on the source which will add some guaranteed ordering between the two systems.

The below code should make it "more likely" to be correct by removing the threads. Assuming that you're using MRI, the threads are "green" so technically can't be running at the same time. That means you're beholden upon the scheduler choosing to run your thread at the "right" time.

```rb
Open3.popen3("my_custom_script with_some_args") do |_in, stdout, stderr|
  for_reading = [stdout, stderr]
  until(for_reading.empty?) do
    wait_timeout = 1
    # IO.select blocks until one of the streams is has something to read
    # or the wait timeout is reached
    readable, _writable, errors = IO.select(for_reading, [], [], wait_timeout)

    # readable is nil in the case of a timeout - loop back again
    if readable.nil?
      Thread.pass
    else
      # In the case that both streams are readable (and thus have content)
      # read from each of them. In this case, we cannot guarantee any order
      # because we recieve the items at essentially the same time.
      # We can still ensure that we don't mix data incorrectly.
      readable.each do |stream|
        buffer = ''
        # loop through reading data until there is an EOF (value is nil)
        # or there is no more data to read (value is empty)
        while(true) do
          tmp = stream.read_nonblock(4096, buffer, exception: false)
          if tmp.nil?
            # stream is EOF - nothing more to read on that one..
            for_reading -= [stream]
            break
          elsif tmp.empty? || tmp == :wait_readable
            # nothing more to read right now...
            # continue on to process the buffer into lines and log them
            break
          end
        end

        if stream == stdout
          buffer.split("\n").each { |line| logger.info(format(:info, line)) }
        elsif stream == stderr
          buffer.split("\n").each { |line| logger.info(format(:error, line)) }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Note that in a system generating a lot of output in a very short period of time there is more likely to be an overlap where things get out of order. This likelihood increases with the amount time taken to read the stream and process it. It would be best to ensure that the absolute minimum processing is done inside the loop. If the formatting (and writing) are expensive, consider moving those items into a separate thread reading from a single queue, and have the code inside the loop only push the buffer (and source identifier) onto the queue.

Comment: Thank you, good answer. In my research I came across this interesting blog in dealing with deadlocks from using popen3, which provides a similar solution http://coldattic.info/post/63/. Note he also watches the process for termination independently, but I'm not sure if that's required with open3 as I think it also waits for the process to finish